# btsnooz_hci.log truncated packet?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, wireshark, hci, l2cap

How to capture full BLE packet on HCI sniffing / wireshark. The packet size and capture size are different, no idea why. How to capture the full packet.

[Please find the packet capture screenshot below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCpgh.png)

I am trying to sniff BLE packets between a device and OEM app. After capturing the log file from android, I tried to view the same on wireshark.

Comment: Exactly how do you capture and extract the log file?

Comment: enable Bluetooth HCI snoop log under developer options of android
Run the OEM application to give out commands.
use adb report gives the HCI log which can be opened in Wireshark